Tailwind Sticky TopBar - scrolls off screen
I have a tool bar with editable area below that as follows

When I scroll scroll that section of the layout the tool bar scrolls off the screen.
I have added relative to the parent div and given sticky property to the tool bar.
Also given overflow-y-auto to the content area. But it does not seem to work.
Screen Link >

You don't need to use overflow-hidden and h-fit because you have already set the height in .tiptap and you can probably change the content of the height from 70lvh to 90vh to make it look more fit. the changes I made
html :
<div class="relative w-full tiptap" style="container-type: inline-size;">

css:
.tiptap {
       height: 90vh;
}

look like this

